# MySQL - Atualizar coluna com valor de data brasileira

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, data

Estou atualizando uma tabela num banco com mais de 100 mil registros para poder realizar futuros SELECTS para gerar um relatório estatistico.

A tabela atualmente tem uma coluna 'Nascimento' do tipo varchar(10) que armazena a data de nascimento do cliente no formato 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Como está em varchar está demorando por volta de 2 minutos para terminar a query.

Então criei uma coluna chamada 'data_nascimento' do tipo date e estou tentando usar o seguinte código para converter os valores da coluna 'Nascimento':

```
update cadastros_dados set data_nascimento = STR_TO_DATE(nascimento,'%d%m%Y')
```

Mas dá o seguinte erro:

[Err] 1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '23/02/1971' for function str_to_date

Por que não está aceitando a data que está armazenada em 'Nascimento' na função STR_TO_DATE? O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando as barras no seu formato

```
update cadastros_dados set data_nascimento = STR_TO_DATE(nascimento,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

documentação da função: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Já coloquei com as barras mas mesmo assim dá o seguinte erro:

Comment: [Err] 1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '20 01 1958' for function str_to_date

Comment: Já descobri o problema. Alguns registros estão dd/mm/yy e outros estão dd mm yyyy. Teria algum jeito de eu atualizar todos estes incorretos sem ter que ser um por um?

Comment: dá um replace, onde tem espaços coloca a /

Comment: @RenanKaicLopes se te ajudou, não esqueça de marcar como resposta. obrigado